# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a `const` defined with multiple functions that are irrevelant to the question, so am just including a sanitized segment that's relevant. Let me know if I should include anything more.

```
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <hr className={hrClasses} />
          <span className={spanClasses}>
            {isTrue ? 'x' : index + 1}
          </span>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

In the browser, I see the warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Since the `hr` element doesn't need a unique key prop, how can I get around this error?

I've tried different variations of keys, such as adding `key={index}` to the `hr` element and re-labelling the `index` key as `id` for the `span`. I'm not sure what else to try. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: This usually happens when you create components or elements in a loop. If you use an index, the keys will be 0..n. Other loops can create the same keys or you could be sharing the index. You could give the index a prefix or suffix to make it unique.

Comment: @DCTID Keys need to be [unique within siblings only](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings). It does not share it with other arrays

Answer (score 12):

You are not applying the key to the parent Fragment.

> You can use <> the same way you’d use any other element except that it doesn’t support keys or attributes. ~ https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

You are using the short syntax of <>  which does not support keys. Use:

```
<React.Fragment key={index}>
      <hr className={styles.hr} />
      <span className={styles.span}>
        {isValidated ? 'x' : index + 1}
      </span>
 <React.Fragment/>
```

Comment: I've actually tried encasing the section in a div with the key, and unfortunately your suggested fix didn't fix the seen error. I appreciate your comment though, that's good to know about `React.Fragment`!

Comment: Please post the rest of your class or component.

Comment: I would like to see the index value. Try logging the index and share the results.

Comment: The index value when logged increments by 1 as expected - "0", "1", "2"

Comment: Updated the above context to include the rest of the component!